# The executable was signed with invalid entitlement

Tags: ios, swift, entitlements

Can any one help me why giving following error with installing Appstore distribution build/release into my iphone.

> Errors: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements. The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. 0xE8008016

When i install build with AdHoc distribution every thing working fine.

I have enabled following services in provisioning profile/ App Id 
 1. App group 
 2. Game center 
 3. In app purchase
 4. Push notification 
   
I have on following capabilities in Xcode 
 1. App group 
 2. Game center 
 3. In app purchase
 4. Push notification

Entitlements file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"      "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
<array>
<string>group.SelfieM</string>
</array>
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have integration Share extension Application in my project while consists following properties

I have enabled following services in provisioning profile/ App Id for Share extension App
 1. App group 
 2. Game center 
 3. In app purchase
 4. Push notification 
   
I have on following capabilities in Xcode for Share extension app
 1. App group 
 2. Game center 
 3. In app purchase
 4. Push notification

Entitlements file for Share extension app  -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"   "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
 <array>
  <string>group.Selfie</string>
 </array>
 <key>get-task-allow</key>
 <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Please suggest me what is problem in this process  …. 
Thanks You